# What is the best practice to secure an unattended Raspberry Pi?

Tags: encryption, ssh, disk-encryption, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project which involves mounting a Raspberry Pi on a self-moving vehicle. I'm looking for the best way to encrypt the Pi (entire file-system, swap, etc.), with the minimum possible impact on performance, in case it falls in the wrong hands.

I also need it to be unlockable via SSH, and ideally, I need it to create a WiFi AP that I will connect to and then unlock it via SSH.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: are you interested in encrypting the entire disk or just specific vulnerable files?

Comment: @MSB Encrypting the entire disk would be preferable, but if that would cost too much in terms of performance than specific files are ok too

Comment: Hey eden, I hope the answer I provided helped answer your question. If you are still unclear on where to go from here I would be more than willing to help out in any way I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Have a few suggestions but no definitive best go to solution since it really depends on your specific use case.

First off look into [BerryBoot](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=244508#p244508), it offers full disk encryption out of the box.

A second alternative is to use any of the TrueCrypt like applications such as [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com) It offers a bunch of options to either perform full disk encryption or make sure that specific vulnerable files are safely encrypted.

A third option, similar to the second is [encrypting directories on the disk](https://wiki.debian.org/TransparentEncryptionForHomeFolder)

If you are more technically inclined and would like to manually perform certain taks it is also possible to use [LUKS/dm-crypt](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch09.en.html#_data_encryption_tips) yourself.

You will have to keep certain things in mind though: The computational power of the Pi is limited so any form of encryption on the devices will cause a performance hit.

Secondly you will have the problem that you will need to manually enter the key each time the device wants to perform an operation, since storing it in a physical form on the device makes it vulnerable to anyone with physical access.

Comment: +1 for BerryBoot, I'll check it out, thanks! I'm currently looking into full disk encryption using LUKS, but it seems like I'm going to have a hard time `chroot`ing into the SD-card since my computer is not compatible with ARM architecture..

Comment: You could always get another Pi that you can use for access.